# Animate Picturebox in VB

Tags: vb.net, loops, events

I am new to VB and just can't figure it out how to animate a button using the MouseHover Event..

I want to create a single loop for all the buttons(picturebox) in my project that will increase the button's size when the user rests the mouse on it.

Maybe something like:

```
For Each Form As Form In Application.OpenForms
      For Each Control As Control In Form.Controls
```

Tks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Stop naming variable the same as it's object. what does `buttons(picturebox)` mean - is it a button or picturebox?

Answer (score 0):

Use Inherits to create a new button (or PictureBox) class for you purpose. Here is the code.

```
Public Class cuteButton
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Button

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseHover(e As EventArgs)
    '
    'Wite code here to change button size or whatever.
    '

    MyBase.OnMouseHover(e)
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to use a common `MouseHover` event to grow your buttons (which I guess is really a Picturebox with an image in it):

```
Private Sub CustomButton_Grow(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Picturebox1.MouseHover, Picturebox2.MouseHover
   'Set a maximum height to grow the buttons to.
   'This can also be set for width depending on your needs!
   Dim maxHeight as single = 50

   If sender.Height < maxHeight then
      sender.Size = New Size(sender.Width+1,sender.Height+1)
   End if
End Sub
```

Then you can reset all buttons in a snap using the `MouseLeave` event. If you want that part animated as well then you can to use a global shrink routine that constantly shrink all buttons but the one in `MouseHover`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This Will Work even if you have 10,000 button or picture box ....

I am Assuming that you only have 1 form and many Buttons ,,, you have to be specific on your question

This Code will work fine with Buttons, Picturebox ,text box

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each cntrl As Control In Controls  ' Looping for each Button as Control
        If TypeOf cntrl Is Button Then
            AddHandler cntrl.MouseEnter, AddressOf cntrl_MouseEnter ' Adding the event and handler
            AddHandler cntrl.MouseLeave, AddressOf cntrl_MouseLeave ' Adding the event and handler

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

```
     '' Assuming you wanna eNlarge everytime the mouse Hover or Enter 

Private Sub cntrl_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    CType(sender, Button).Size = New Point(CType(sender, Button).Size.Width + 50, CType(sender, Button).Size.Height + 50)
End Sub
     '' Here it goes back normal size
Private Sub cntrl_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    CType(sender, Button).Size = New Point(CType(sender, Button).Size.Width - 50, CType(sender, Button).Size.Height - 50)
End Sub
```